# old ssl certficate didn't go away on apache2

Tags: apache-2.2

I have replaced the old ssl certficate with new one and restart apache several time but the old certificate still show  on web browser and when  I run a command

> openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -showcerts

also I have delete all old certficate files. so not sure where apache still read these certficate. and not read the new one.
here is my ssl.conf

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:443

SSLEngine on
SSLOptions +StrictRequire

<Directory />
SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>

SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1 +SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:+SHA1:+MD5:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

 SSLMutex file:/usr/apache2/logs/ssl_mutex

SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom 1024
SSLRandomSeed connect file:/dev/urandom 1024

SSLSessionCache shm:/usr/apache2/logs/ssl_cache_shm
SSLSessionCacheTimeout 600

SSLPassPhraseDialog builtin
SSLCertificateFile /usr/apache2/conf/ssl.crt/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/apache2/conf/ssl.key/server.key

SSLVerifyClient none
SSLProxyEngine off

<IfModule mime.c>
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert      .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl         .crl
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Post your apache config files...

Comment: Did you restart, and not just do a reload or graceful restart?

Comment: @shane, yes I did stop and restart not reload.

Comment: @Jeff, I have added my apache ssl.conf

Comment: How about the port 443 virtual host?